# Ordering of cells within tensorflow MultiRNNCell

Tags: tensorflow

Could someone please clarify the order of cells in a tensorflow MultiRNNCell ? In the l-tuple of states where l is the number of layers, does the index 0 correspond to the layer closest to the input, or the one just before the output ? I couldn't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of class MultiRNNCell at tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py, it seems index 0 corresponds to the layer closest to the input.

```
@property
def output_size(self):
    return self._cells[-1].output_size
```